# Can disc and god versions coexist on xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, red-dead-redemption

In my case, I have Red Dead Redemption GOTY and I manually installed it on HDD. This week the digital version is 75% off on xboxmarketplace. I kinda like it that I don't have to insert discs every time and I don't need to worry the discs will wear out one day.

While if I buy the digital version, do I have to uninstall the GOTY version first? The GOTY version does come with some extra perks (for example, Solomon’s Folly single player gang hideout, which is only included in GOTY for xbox360). If they can coexist, I want to use the digital GOD one for zombie and multiplayer. HDD space is not my concern here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to uninstall your GOTY edition.

However, despite installing your original copy, you will still need to redownload the game. The data provided in a "online and downloaded" game differs from the data in a "physical disc and installed" game.

Provided the extras included in the GOTY edition were infact DLC codes, which is the usual procedute for extra content, your new version of Red Dead Redemption should still have access to these DLCs. As such, your save should work with either, aswell.

The best way to see if two versions of the game are "the same" is to check the achievements listing. If the GOTY edition registers as a different game, it will also have a seperate list of achievements.